# Which equipment to use for testing performance of AM, FM, and DAB

Tags: signal-analysis, software-defined-radio, frequency-modulation, amplitude-modulation

I want to test the performance of AM, FM and DAB radio in RTL-SDR. I want to measure sensitivity, adjacent channel selectivity, cross-modulation/blocking, and third-order intermodulation to be some of the metrics. From [the ETSI document](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/303300_303399/30334501/01.01.00_20/en_30334501v010100a.pdf) for broadcast sound receivers, it is found that to conduct these performance tests, I need 2 signal generators, 1 signal analyzer, and an RF combiner. Since I don't have much experience working with this equipment, I don't know which type of signal generator/combiner to buy (as there are so many types in the market).

Can someone provide me details on which equipment will be suitable for testing AM/FM/DAB?

Comment: what do you mean with "performance of AM, FM and DAB"? You can analyze the performance of a specific *receiver*, not of a broadcasting *standard* (that would be like saying you want to test the performance of "road network" in terms of speed, horse powers and gasoline usage). Could you elaborate on **what thing** you want to test for these properties?

Comment: By performance, I mean sensitivity, channel selectivity, and intermodulation of AM/FM/DAB in RTL-SDR with the commercial radio tuner used in automobiles. The AM/FM/DAB tuner used in vehicles have used this ETSI document for broadcast receivers to evaluate their performance. I would like to do the same with an RTL-SDR or LimeSDR

Comment: @user28 Tell me if I got it right: you need a recommendation for test equipment that would let you certify an RTL-SDR for compliance with that ETSI standard, when used as an AM, FM and/or DAB receiver. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. You are right I need a recommendation for the test equipments.

Comment: But an RTL-SDR is not a receiver for any of these standards on its own! It takes *software* to make it one. Hence, the S in **S**DR! So, you need to find out what software you want to use first, before you can think about getting measurement equipment.

Comment: By software, you mean GNU Radio or LabVIEW? I am using GNU Radio to implement AM/FM/DAB. I suppose GNU radio is the right software for testing